# If $f(x) = \sin^4(x)$, find $f^{(2000)}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I'm stuck with this question about Maclaurin series.

> $f(x)= \sin^4x$; find $f^{(2000)}$.

I have expanded $f(x)$ and gotten:

$$\frac18(3-4\cos(2x) + \cos(4x))$$

How do I change it to Maclaurin series as there is a constant in the expansion? 
Explanation is appreciated. Thanks

edit:
I was told to solve using Maclaurin series for $cos x$ where $cos x:$

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$

Comment: It would be a question about Maclaurin series, if it asked about $f^{(2000)}(0)$. As it is, the series won't help you much, because after differentiating it 2000 times, there are still infinitely manyt terms remaining.

Answer (score 5):

If $g(x) = \cos(mx)$, then $g^{(4n)} = m^{4n} g(x)$. Now we have $$f(x) = \dfrac{3-4 \cos(2x) + \cos(4x)}8$$ Hence,
$$f^{(2000)}(x) = \dfrac{-4 \cdot 2^{2000} \cdot \cos(2x) + 4^{2000} \cdot \cos(4x)}8$$

Comment: $$g^{4(n)}=m^{4n}g(x)?$$